# Data Drive Unit Test - Programmatically Skipping Rows

Tags: .net, unit-testing, data-driven-tests

Is there a way to programmatically skip rows in a data drive unit test?  I want to run all rows on our build server, but only one row when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is generate a test that only performs its action on one row. Then create another test that is a single liner, calling the single row test. Make this your actual data-driven test.

Include the data-driven (skeleton) tests in your nightly build process and use the single row one during debugging.

Comment: We sort of did this.  We have a method that is used to get the list of data elements.  If we are in debug mode, we only get the first one.